# Filtering on object properties not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter within an ng-repeat like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="file in files | filter: { values.filetype: 'Form' }">
```

If I change `values.filetype: 'Form'` to, say, `id: 1`, the filter works correctly. So how do I get it to work with the first property?

Edit: the structure of the data is like this:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "values":
        "title: "sldkfjsd",
        "filetype": "Form"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved with the following syntax:

```
filter: { values: { filetype: 'Form'} }
```